# iPhone Google Maps API V3 User Current location and show Restaurants

Tags: javascript, iphone, google-maps

I am trying to make a website using Google API V3 to show your current location and nearby restaurants or cafes..
I tried this code on google's tutorial but i cant get that this api will show my current position on the map
here is the code: 
there is a pyrmont and i can change it with another latitude and longitude but i could not make it useful with navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(); 
Thanks

AND i know there is this code: but i dont know how to use the get position out of it...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var map;
  var infowindow;

if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
    } else {
      alert('geolocation not supported');
    }

    function success(position) {
      alert(position.coords.latitude + ', ' + position.coords.longitude);
    }

    function error(msg) {
      alert('error: ' + msg);
    }

  function initialize() {
    var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(48.195201,16.369547);

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: pyrmont,
      zoom: 15
    });

    var request = {
      location: pyrmont,
      radius: 500,
      types: ['cafe']
    };
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.search(request, callback);
  }

  function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  function createMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.setContent(place.name);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED.

So, the search function was returning zero results on my actual location, so when I offset my actual location to be closer to your original (since I don't know the density of results matching your query) it works for me. You'll have to edit the 6.6 and 89.45 to see it work, but then you'll need to do something with the search itself if you want it to be useful

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
#map_canvas{width:500px;height:500px;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var map;
  var infowindow;

  function initialize(position) {
    //var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(48.195201,16.369547);
    var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude+6.6,position.coords.longitude+89.45);
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: pyrmont,
      zoom: 15
    });
    var a = new google.maps.Marker({position: pyrmont,map: map,icon:'http://www.blind-summit.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/google-map/images/marker_blue.png'});
    var request = {
      location: pyrmont,
      radius: 500,
      types: ['cafe']
    };
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.search(request, callback);
  }

  function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
      }
    }
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.ZERO_RESULTS){
   alert('zero results near this location');
    }
  }

  function createMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.setContent(place.name);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function(){
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so what will i do with this line?
var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(48.195201,16.369547);

Comment: it doesnt work, if i dont change this pyrmont, it shows still only the same location.. not somewhereelse..

Comment: When I run it, I get your search results and my location. Is your goal to search AROUND the user location?

Comment: Hi, i have another question, how can i add places information like address, rating, website ... because on these clouds, it comes only the name of the places, but it could be cool if it shows the address and some other stuff..

Comment: you just need to edit the `infowindow.setContent(place.name);` line...for instance: `infowindow.setContent(place.name+'<br/>'+place.vicinity+'<br/>Rating: '+place.rating);`

Answer (score 0):

Code in previous example is not working, I have fixed the code with a little changes, I hope this will help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
    <title>Google Maps</title> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&region=uk&language=en&sensor=true"></script>
    <!--<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
</head> 
<body>

    <div id="map" style="width: 1200px; height: 600px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 15,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5121, -0.1043),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(myEvent)
        {
            getPOI(myEvent.latLng);
        });


        function getPOI(latLng)
        {
            var request = {
                location: latLng,
                radius: 500,
                types: ['cafe']
            };
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
            service.search(request, callback);
        }

        function callback(results, status) {
            console.log(results);
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    createMarker(results[i]);
                }
            }
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.ZERO_RESULTS){
                alert('zero results near this location');
            }
        }

        function createMarker(place) {
            //var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            //icon: place.icon,
                            map: map,
                            position: place.geometry.location,
                            title: place.name
                        });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.setContent(place.name);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
    }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```